# Is dlnorm is equal to dnorm?

Tags: statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

It might be silly question. But I want the clarification.
If X follows lognormal then log(X) follows normal distribution
I want to know dlnorm is not equal to dnorm, why?? But plnorm is equal to pnorm!!!

```
> u=5
> s=0.5
> u
[1] 5
> s
[1] 0.5
> T=84.5
> dist_log=plnorm(T, meanlog=u, sdlog=s)
> dist_log
[1] 0.1299776194
> dist_norm=pnorm(log(T), mean=u, sd=s)
> dist_norm
[1] 0.1299776194
> den_log=dlnorm(T, meanlog=u, sdlog=s)
> den_log
[1] 0.005006388135
> den_norm=dnorm(log(T), mean=u, sd=s)
> den_norm
[1] 0.4230397974
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the probability functions `pnorm()` and `plnorm()` will give the same results, given an appropriate data transformation, and that's an important insight.  However, `dnorm()` and `dlnorm()` will not.

Here's another way to think of it: the `d__` functions return the height of a curve at a given point, and the `p__` functions return the area *under* the curve.  Statistically, the `d__` functions aren't often much use to us by themselves, since the curve height doesn't really mean anything.  In fact, the curve itself is scaled so that the total area underneath is 1.  What *does* typically matter is area - and the area of given regions corresponds to probability.

Here's a visual that will hopefully help...

```
curve(dnorm(x,mean=5,sd=0.5), from=0, to=10)
abline(v=log(84.5))
points(x=log(84.5), y=dnorm(log(84.5), mean=5, sd=0.5))

curve(dlnorm(x,meanlog=5,sdlog =0.5), from=0, to=600)
abline(v=84.5)
points(x=84.5, y=dlnorm(84.5, meanlog=5, sdlog=0.5))
```

The area to the left of the vertical line is the same in both plots, but the height of the curve at that point is different.